# setText to TextView in Android Studio is not working

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to change TextView content according to signal strength of wifi after I press the button.
Here is some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                wifiUpdate();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void wifiUpdate() {
        final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DataDisplay);
        String temp = "Starting";
        t1.setText(temp);
        //some other code, where I using setText to assign variable, so it cant be static
    }
```

In activity_main.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="490dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I click the button - it stays saying "Hello world". Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: are you doing any work on the UI thread that may prevent the text from being updated timely? I see comment "//some other code", make sure that code is not taking to long to execute.

Comment: @DonHa "//some other code" is a loop, where I am requesting wifi signal strength and trying to setText it. Data retrieving part works 100% fine (I checked in Logcat), but TextView is not changing at all. Is there a problem?

Comment: comment out the loop and see if the text updated.

Comment: @DonHa, hmm, updated correctly... so I need to investigate my loop. Is this need to be asynchronous?  Here is the full code btw https://pastebin.com/0pHfdYeT

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the while loop is what causes UI not to update, can't have that on UI thread. Move that to AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

`t1.setText( "" + temp);`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button; 
TextView t1; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DataDisplay);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                wifiUpdate();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void wifiUpdate() {
        
        String temp = "Starting";
        t1.setText(""+temp);
        //some other code, where I using setText to assign variable, so it cant be static
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DataDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="490dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, I have tested.Just clean the project and build again if that doesn't work try to do Invalidate Caches/Restart from Files in Android Studio.

Additional you can do is to remove the text tag from TEXTVIEW in XML,even with text tag it won't give any problem.